# What is the meaning of $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4?

Tags: php, hex

Specifically, what does the `($c1 & 0x03) << 4` do?

Is 0x03 hex notation?

Comment: Try it and see. Then consult the manual for `&` (bitwise-and) and `<<` (left shift). Break down the parts. Yes, `0x03` is in hexadecimal (and is equivalent to 3, but often times using hex makes it more clear to see the special bit patterns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does mean first operation do logically AND with HEX value 0x03(that is 3 in HEX or (0011) in Binary).and then left Shift 4 places.example

let u have $c = 34.
then first it performs $c & 3 which is (100010 BITWISE AND 000011) which Gives you (000010) 
and then It shifts 4 digit on left position and restore new value in $c i.e (100000) or 32 in decimal.

Hope it is Helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This takes the low two bits of the `$c1` value, and shifts it 4 bits to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 0x is hex.  That is doing a bitwise AND of $c1 and the hex 03 value, then left shifting the result 4 places (powers of 2).